# How to connect to a remote Database in Django using PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, remote-access

Me and my friend are doing to joint app together and was wondering if there is an easy way to connect to his database so I can migrate as well?

Thank you
Onur

Comment: You just fill in the host in the `'HOST'` part. There is nothing different. Of course in order to migrate, the user that you use needs priveleges to create and alter tables and fields.

Comment: Use any *Database-as-a-Services (DBaaS)*